# Rails two way association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, orm

I've implemented a model with `modified_by_id` and `modifies_id` self-referencing attributes to persist "dirty" state of some models.

```rb
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :models do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.modified_by_id :integer
      t.modifies_id :integer
    end
  end
end
```

This double association has the intention of speeding (and simplifying) two queries

- the latest version of things `where(modified_by_id: nil)`
- the persisted version of things `where(modifies_id: nil)`

Everything works well when handling the ids manually, but I can't model it properly with relations.

```rb
    has_one :modifies, class_name: 'Some::Model', foreign_key: 'modifies_id'
  belongs_to :modified_by, class_name: 'Some::Model', foreign_key: 'modified_by_id'
```

Using it so populates only one of the ids when calling `model.modifies = new_model`

And this:

```rb
 has_one :modifies, class_name: 'Some::Model', foreign_key: 'modifies_id'
  belongs_to :modified_by, class_name: 'Some::Model', inverse_of: :modifies, foreign_key: 'modified_by_id'
```

pupulates only one model with the same id twice (modifes_id == modofies_by_id)

How should this be modeled?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if `A.modifies = B` then `B.modified_by = A`, right? Then you do not need both foreign-keys, because from one you can always deduce the other? And to be sure: it is not possible that one can modify multiple models, right?

Comment: yes, a single reference would suffice, but then you'll have to hit the DB twice or a more complex SQL to grab entries that are not mentioned by any FK, right?